# Rigidbody2d pressed into each other, Why?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, rigid-bodies

I have several objects with Rigidbody2d that I stack on top of each other. As soon as there are a few more, they get presst in each other and I just can't understand why. can someone tell me why this is happening?

Rigidbody2d

- dynamic
- Mass between 1 and 20 depends on Object
- Collision detection: Continuous
- Interpolate: Interoplate

i use Box and Polygon Collider.

Global physic settings i changed Max Linear Correction to 0.0001 because
when this value is higher the objects begin to jitter.

This is what happened:
[see here a .gif who show what happened](https://forum.unity.com/threads/rigidbody2d-pressed-into-each-other-why.1103986/)

please help.